# How to split a 64-bit number into eight 8-bit values?

Tags: c, types, bit-manipulation

Is there a simple way to split one 64-bit (`unsigned long long`) variable into eight `int8_t` values?

For example:

```c
//1001000100011001100100010001100110010001000110011001000110011111
unsigned long long bigNumber = 10455547548911899039;
int8_t parts[8] = splitULongLong(bigNumber);
```

`parts` would be something along the lines of:

> [0] 10011111
>
> [1] 10010001
>
> [2] 00011001
>
> ...
>
> [7] 10010001

Comment: bitshifting is your friend

Comment: You could use a cast: `(int8_t *)&_64bitVar`. Mind for big/little endian though.

Comment: Yeah, do you care about endianness? What's the ultimate goal here?

Comment: @Potatoswatter Endianness is paramount. The goal is verifying adjacency on a 2-dimensional board through 1-dimensional values.

Comment: Your example leaves the impression that with a `0x` formatted integer you would be able to specify that integer in binary?

Comment: I don't see how endianness matters for checking adjacency.

Comment: In C, an eight-element array is indexed with subscripts from zero to seven, not one to eight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```c
 {
   uint64_t v= _64bitVariable;
   uint8_t i=0,parts[8]={0};
   do parts[i++]=v&0xFF; while (v>>=8);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First you shouldn't play such games with signed values, this only complicates the issue. Then you shouldn't use `unsigned long long` directly, but the appropriate fixed width type `uint64_t`. This may be `unsigned long long`, but not necessarily.

Any byte (assuming 8 bit) in such an integer you may obtain by shifting and masking the value:

```
#define byteOf(V, I) (((V) >> (I)*8)&UINT64_C(0xFF))
```

To initialize your array you would place calls to that macro inside an initializer.

BTW there is no standard "binary" format for integers as you seem to be assuming.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, by repeating it with values `0 .. 7` for `I`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a Union to split the data up without any movement or processing.

This leaves you with the problem of the resulting table being in hte wrong order which can be easily solved with a macro (if you have lots of hard coded values) or a simple "8-x" subscript calculation.

```
#define rv(ss) = 8 - ss;


union SameSpace {
unsigned long long _64bitVariable;
int8_t _8bit[8];
} samespace;

_64bitVariable = 0x1001000100011001100100010001100110010001000110011001000110011111;

if (_8bit[rv(1)] == 0x10011111) {
   printf("\n correct");
}
```

Comment: This answer adopts the question’s use of `0x` notation for binary, which does not work in C.

Comment: The `rv` macro definition has three problems: Function-like macros must not have a space after the macro name and before the parenthesis, occurrences of the parameter name in the replacement list should be parenthesized, and it is not portable (does not account for different endianness in different implementations).

Comment: @Eric Postpischil - thanks for the syntax check. I have not got a C compiler available at the moment :-)

Comment: Beware, I suggested the use of a union [previously](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2747324/329079) and @Nils Pipenbrinck was astute enough to note that unions are undefined by the c-standard.

Comment: This method will work different on little and big endian machines ?

Answer (score 1):

I think if it can be this:
 64bit num %8 ,save this result,and then minus the result  then divide the result by 8
last save divided num and save  (64bit num %8) num, and last you get two 8bit num , and you can use this two num to replace 64bit num 。 but when you need to operate , you may need to operate 8bit num to 64 bit mun

Comment: %8 preserves the lowest 3 bits, not 8 bits, you need %256 (or & 255) to mask off the lowest 8 bits.